# How to write custom text on JavaFX 2.2 cursor?

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, javafx-2

I want a cursor that displays the coordinates of the place the mouse is pointing to, besides the pointer itself (it should look like a crosshair with little numbers is bottom right corner, that change when the mouse is moving). How to achive such effect efficiently? I tried to use the tooltip mechanism, but then the text lags behind the cursor a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Text` object with the current coordinates, snapshot it to an `Image`, and then create a `WritableImage` from that and any other cursor decoration you need. Then wrap the `WritableImage` in an `ImageCursor`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.ImageCursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MouseCoordinateCursor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        root.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                root.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
        });

        root.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            final int padding = 9 ;
            final int offset = 6 ;
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                Text text = new Text(String.format("[%.1f,%.1f]", e.getX(), e.getY()));
                Image textImage = text.snapshot(null, null);
                int width = (int)textImage.getWidth();
                int height = (int)textImage.getHeight();
                WritableImage cursorImage = new WritableImage(width + offset, height + offset);
                cursorImage.getPixelWriter().setPixels(offset, offset, width, height, textImage.getPixelReader(), 0, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
                    cursorImage.getPixelWriter().setColor(i, padding/2, Color.BLACK);
                    cursorImage.getPixelWriter().setColor(padding/2, i, Color.BLACK);
                }
                root.setCursor(new ImageCursor(cursorImage));
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the solution I employed, But the Text is lagging - it is not always in the same position relative to cursor.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, see what you mean. Try this instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a label, and change the text inside the mouse moved event everytime that the mouse coordinates changes.

Comment: As I commented below - the label would be lagging and will not be in the same position relative to the cursor.